# Combining rows to create two columns of data

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I'm a bit confused on how to do this query properly. I have a table that looks like this. Where district 0 represent a value that should be applied to all district (global).

```
[ district ] [ code ] [ value ]
     1          A         11
     1          C         12
     2          A         13
     2          B         14
     0          B         15
```

I have built a query (below) to combine the "global value" on each district.

```
[ district ] [ code ] [ district value ] [ global value ]
      1         A            11               null        -> row 1
      1         B           null               15         -> row 2
      1         C            12               null        -> row 3
      2         A            13               null        -> row 4
      2         B            14                15         -> row 5
      2         C           null              null        -> row 6 (optional)
```

I did it by joining on the list of all possible district/code.

```
select all_code.district, all_code.code, table_d.value, table_g.value
  from (select distinct b.district, a.code
          from temp_table a
         inner join (select distinct district
                      from temp_table
                     where district <> 0) b
            on 1 = 1) all_code
  left join temp_table table_d
    on table_d.code = all_code.code
   and table_d.district = all_code.district
  left join temp_table table_g
    on table_g.code = all_code.code
   and table_g.district = 0
```

This query works great but seems pretty ugly. Is there a better way of doing this? (note that I don't care if row #6 is there or not).

Here's a script if needed.

```
create table temp_table
(
  district VARCHAR2(5) not null,
  code     VARCHAR2(5) not null,
  value    VARCHAR2(5) not null
);


insert into temp_table (district, code, value)
values ('1', 'A', '11');
insert into temp_table (district, code, value)
values ('1', 'C', '12');
insert into temp_table (district, code, value)
values ('2', 'A', '13');
insert into temp_table (district, code, value)
values ('2', 'B', '14');
insert into temp_table (district, code, value)
values ('0', 'B', '15');
```

Comment: What would you want to show instead of the null for district value? ultimately, are you wanting district if it exists, and global if district doesn't exist, because we could just apply that logic into a single column for you.

Comment: @GB I'm looking to have case 1 to 5 (with 6 optional) as output to the query. 4 columns

Comment: OK 4 columns - that was only an extension of the main query - what do you want instead of null? or if you prefer - what is wrong with case2?

Comment: @GB I might not been very clear. The query works great, it already return the 6 cases. I just find it very ugly and I'm curious to know if there's a better way if doing this. I modified the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one of the options. Since you are on 10g you can make use of partition outer join(`partition by()` clause) to fill the gaps:

```
with DCodes(code) as(
  select 'A' from dual union all
  select 'B' from dual union all
  select 'C' from dual
),
DGlobal(code, value1) as(
  select code
       , value
    from temp_table
   where district = 0
)
select tt.district
     , dc.code
     , tt.value
     , dg.value1 as global_value
  from temp_table tt
       partition by(tt.district)
       right join DCodes dc 
               on (dc.code = tt.code)
       left join DGlobal dg
              on (dg.code = dc.code)
 where tt.district != 0
 order by 1, 2
```

Result:

```
DISTRICT  CODE  VALUE  GLOBAL_VALUE
--------  ----  -----  ------------
1         A     11                 
1         B            15           
1         C     12                 
2         A     13                 
2         B     14     15           
2         C
```

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that a lot of the "ugliness" comes from a lack of lookup tables for `district` and `code`. Without an authoritative source for those, you have to fabricate one from the values that are in use (hence the sub-queries with `distinct`).

In terms of cleaning up the query you have, the best I can come up with is to remove an unnecessary sub-query and use the proper syntax for the cross join:

```
SELECT   a.district,
         b.code,
         c.value1,
         d.value1
FROM     (SELECT DISTINCT district FROM temp_table WHERE district <> 0) a
         CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT code FROM temp_table) b
         LEFT JOIN temp_table c
            ON b.code = c.code AND a.district = c.district
         LEFT JOIN temp_table d
            ON b.code = d.code AND d.district = 0
ORDER BY district, code
```